# Strange start-up behavior

Tags: boot, bios, post

I'm trying to repurpose a machine that I was previously using to run Mythbuntu. It's only been a couple of months since it was last running, but now I'm getting strange behavior when I turn it on.

What happens is this:

- the power light comes on
- the fan spins up
- both power light and fan stay on for around 10 seconds
- they both then cut out (the light immediately, the fan takes a second or so to spin down)
- 3 or 4 seconds after this, the whole cycle repeats itself

This happens indefinitely. I have to either pull the plug or hold down the power button to stop it. At no point during this cycle does the connected screen come on, so I can't even get into a BIOS or anything. There are no beeps.

I don't even know how to begin diagnosing this. Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: The motherboard might be damaged. Should check in the repair center.

Answer (score 0):

No beeps likely means it's not POSTing, which is a pretty low level failure.  You have a few choices:

- Reset the BIOS - pull the CMOS battery or short the jumper to reset the BIOS settings (you can likely google for the motherboard manual to find exact steps)
- Boot with minimal hardware - disconnect all the drives and any add-on cards and see if you can get it to POST then.  Add items back one at a time.

Comment: Hmm, even with the CMOS battery out and the SSD unplugged it exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Any add-on cards (video, sound, etc?)  Minimal memory would also be worth testing, as would reseating everything . . .